# Suggestion required to design partitioning in cassandra

Tags: design-patterns, cassandra, database-partitioning

I have to design the database for customers having prices for millions of materials they acquire through multiple suppliers for the next 24 months. So the database will store prices on a daily basis for every material supplied by a specific supplier for the next 24 months. So we keep past data. Now lookups will happen on:

1. Find the price for a material by the supplier as of the specific date by a customer.
2. Find the price for a material by the supplier for a time period by a customer.

I can think for the primary key as:

1. Partition key: (customer Id, material Id, supplier Id, date) 
   -- will this end up in perf issues as it will make so many partitions in long run?
2. Partition Key: (customer Id, material Id, supplier Id, monthbucket), clustering key: date
   -- monthbucket will store data for material on monthly basis on same partition and will 
   have value like '202002' for Feb 2020 dates.

Another question is how can I make sure my data distributes evenly across nodes.

Note:

1. combination of customer, material, supplier and date is unique.
2. two customer can have similar material ids.

Key Points:
1. Some customers can have a very small data set while others can have huge data. How well we can distribute data evenly across partitions as Date is a constant field for all customers. Also, material Ids can be the same among different customers as that is there internal representation (maybe a numeric or alphanumeric)

2. Number of Suppliers per customer and material id varies from 1 - 20 in number.
   do you have any suggestions or questions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many suppliers do you have per customer. Because you always have queries on the customer ID & material ID, then I suggest that at least that columns are making into partition key. If you have too many suppliers, you can move it into partition key as well. And I would avoid having monthly bucket - it will make querying hard.

So you can go with following primary keys:

1. `((customer, material, supplier), date)`
2. `((customer, material) supplier, date)`

both will allow to have both queries:

1. `select * from table where customer = ... and material = ... and supplier = ... and date = ...`
2. `select * from table where customer = ... and material = ... and supplier = ... and date >= start and date <= end`

but I would recommend to go with 1st one the partitions won't be too big, and not too small.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex for your suggestion it is really helpful. Just to answer your question: ''It depends on how many suppliers do you have per customer"
- Number of Suppliers per customer and material id varies from 1 - 20 in number.
Also Some customers can have a very small data set while others can have huge data. How well we can distribute data evenly across partitions as Date is a constant field for all customers

Comment: if you have max 20 suppliers per customer/material, then you can move it from partition key into clustering columns - you'll have max 14k rows per partition. If you have a lot of customers & materials  - then it won't be a problem as every combination will generate a different partition key and data will be spread over nodes

Comment: Thanks, Alex i got your point. Let say if I just have to serve #1 item i.e. "Find the price for a material by the supplier as of the specific date by a customer." Then should you include the date in partition key? Is so what about the number of partitions will it affect the database perf anyhow?

Comment: I would suggest not to put `date` into partition key, as you won't be able to do a query with date range.  Usually the number of partitions affects some things, as memory consumption, as we need more memory for bloom filter if we have more partitions... Also, very small rows not always optimal for performance

Comment: Thanks, Alex I understood your point. Just one more thing, I have customer Id as number values like 1,2,3,4,....100 (we call it tenant id) and material ids are alphanumeric which are specific to the customer (which means fo millions of items they will end up in having similar numerics). Will this ends up in similar hash keys and thus into single node as per partition key combination). Is it not a problem to divide data equally among nodes? Or Cassandra has some intelligence to allocate nodes based on available disk space. Any thought?

Comment: No, Cassandra allocates data to nodes based only on hashing of the partition key. But in your case, it's a combination of customer ID & material ID - columns are combined together, like this: `col1:col2:...` and then hash is calculated.

Comment: Ok thanks, Alex, I will dump the same data and see how it works and will share if I find something new. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Hi @Alex would you like to share your thoughts on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274789/how-i-can-process-my-payload-to-insert-data-in-multiple-tables-with-consistency